# Why does this object property return NaN?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have a undefined object at the top of my page:

```
var paddelY = {};
```

Then IN the draw loop, I define it (Otherwise I get an error that mouseY is undefined):

```
paddelY = { 
    1 : mouseY + height*0.03,  //Nuber
    2 : this[1] - height*0.00275 //NaN
};
```

However, if I were to log `paddelY[2]` to the console, it would be `NaN`.

Comment: where do you defined the variable "height"?

Comment: 'this' is not in the paddelY object context

Comment: in this case `this` will be a reference to whatever scope you are un when you are defining the `paddleY` object, not the `paddleY` object itself.

Comment: Actually the problem this[1]. You cannot access this in an object literal declaration.

Comment: height is a variable from p5.js which is basically in this context equal to my or your whole screen.

Comment: So I should just use paddelY[1]  ?

Comment: Are you sure you need to use object? I think an array would be fine for you, unless you can't use the 0th index, and have to use 1, and 2.

Comment: @klenium the actual object is has about 20 more properties and each one goes down `height*0.00275`, So I think it would be better to use an object.

Comment: @Manu But do you need their keys? Or you just want to store 22 values in one variable? If you don't give your "property" a name (like `paddelY.theFirstProp`) or when the numbers matter (like `var years = { 1950: ..., 2000: ...}`, use arrays.

Comment: @klenium I didn't realize I could do the same thing with an  array.

Comment: @Manu Why no? `var paddelY = [];` `paddelY[0] = mouseY + height*0.03; paddelY[1] = paddelY[0] - height*0.00275;`

Comment: @klenium Thanks ill try that.

Comment: @Manu Also don't forget to accept Marc B's answer (click on the mark sign under the votes) if that solved your problem. What I told you is just a suggestion, because I think you don't use it how you should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're defining a new object. `this[1]` won't be available until the entire object has been parsed, so you're doing `undefined - height`, which results in `NaN`.

```
paddelY = { 1 : mouseY + height *0.03 };
paddelY[2] = paddelY[1] - height*0.00275;
```

would work